# zsh: change completion rules and recompile .zwc file

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

In `zsh`, ssh and scp use host completion from `/etc/hosts`. However, they try to match hostnames even if I use capital letters and when I am obviously referring to a file, not a host:

```
$ scp -rp F<tab>
FOO.txt foo.mydomain.com
```

I would like to disable this feature. I have changed following line in `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_ssh`

```
compadd -M 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z} r:|.=* r:|=*' "$@" $config_hosts
```

to

```
compadd  "$@" $config_hosts
```

Now when I start typing my ssh command and autocomplete the hostname using tab, `ssh foo<tab>`, I get an error:

```
_all_labels:39: command not found: -J
```

what does it mean, and how can I fix it ?

A second problem is, I am unable to recompile the completion file after I made my changes to Unix/_ssh:

```
zcompile Unix/ Unix.zwc
zcompile: can't open file: Unix.zwc
```

this is what I get when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd>:

```
$ scp -rp TE
Trace output left in /tmp/zsh10048scp3 (up-history to view)
TESTING.txt
testing          testing.mydomain.com
```

where TESTING.txt is a file, and `testing` and `testing.mydomain.com` are hostnames

## UPDATE:

I have noticed that I get the above `_all_labels:39` error only for hosts, which have `ProxyCommand` in `~/.ssh/config`, ie:

```
Host testing        testing.mydomain.com
    Hostname        testing.mydomain.com
    User            root    
    PubkeyAuthentication    yes
    StrictHostKeyChecking   yes
    UserKnownHostsFile  ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    ProxyCommand        ssh server2.mydomain.com nc %h %p
```

Comment: There isn't enough info to answer the first question. the output of `_complete_debug` , normally used by pressing `^X?` at the point you would normally press tab would be helpful. And the site dislikes asking multiple questions in one post. the second question is easy and documented in the man page how to use zcompile. you might've already got an answer for that had the first question lacking more info wasn't attached to it.

Comment: @llua - I have updated my question. Not sure if the debug info is any helpful.

Comment: that `/tmp/zsh9900ssh4` file is what is of interest, assuming `testing` is a file in your pwd.

Comment: and the error `_all_labels:39: command not found: -J` didn't appear in your attempt.

Comment: @llua - actually, I just noticed, I only get the `_all_labels:39` error for hosts, which have  `ProxyCommand` in `~/.ssh/config`. Such as:  `ProxyCommand            ssh server2.mydomain.com nc %h %p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that you have not removed "\" in the previous line of */usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_ssh*, while making your change:

```
_wanted hosts expl 'remote host name' \
 compadd -M 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z} r:|.=* r:|=*' "$@" $config_hosts
```

I did that (removed the continuation char "\" at the *wanted* line), and got exactly the same error you have:

```
_all_labels:39: command not found: -J
```

Another possibility is that you might have put some extra whitespace after "\" accidentally, thereby disabling it.

Regarding the second part of your question, I believe the correct syntax to use is:

```
zcompile Unix.zwc Unix/*
```

(compile everything in Unix/ to Unix.zwc)

Comment: thanks, you are spot on. I had a comment in between the two lines. Removing it fixed the  `_all_labels:39: command not found: -J` error.

Comment: Please see my update on your zcompile issue.